# What types of connectors should I use to connect an HC-06 to an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-06

I am new to electronics and I need to connect an Arduino Uno with an HC-06 Bluetooth module.

The problem is that I don't know what types of connectors I should use.

I know I need some Dupont wires but there are 3 types: **male to male** - **male to female** - **female to female**.

So my question is: what type of connector should I use?

Comment: Since you haven't shared a picture of your module, I guess that the module has 4 male pins on the pcb (if it has backplane).
And Arduino Uno pins are all female. So, "male to female" dupont cables would give you a go. 
If you don't want to go with just the wires but ready to use connectors, there will be many options depends on what you expect from a connector in your setup.
Since you are new to electronics, with this module, believe me connector would be your least issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on the exact package of you HC-06. All of the ones I have are like this picture. If you have one like this, you will need male to female jumper cables. I would recommend a breadboard as well if you plan on connecting anything additional.

[image]

Comment: yeap mine is also like that

Comment: so with arduino uno + hc-06 + male to female i can connect right ?

Comment: Yep, the cables are named based on anatomy. The male one has the pins and the female has the receptacle. Male and female connect together. So, the arduino uno has female connectors which will require a male connector on one end of the cable. On the other end, the bluetooth module has male connectors which will require a female to plug into. So, male->female is the cable that you will need.   See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_connectors_and_fasteners